# How do I filter a list of LiveData objects in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

The title might be worded weirdly or unclear, but I am creating a game using android studio and Kotlin as the language. I have a repository that retrieves the score to the game (also stores it):

```
  val readAllData: LiveData<List<ScoreDB>> = scoreDao.getScore()
```

Then in my leaderboard composable function I have:

```
    val scoreList : LiveData<List<ScoreDB>> = vm.readAllData
```

I want to filter out this list to display the top 10 scores. After scoreList is filtered to only the top ten score, I was going to put it in a lazyColumn using something like this:

```
                //TODO List highest scores from database in this lazycolumn
                items(10){idx->
                    ScoreRow(idx)


                }
```

I am stuck on how to filter the scoreList to contain only the top 10 scores and then to display them in the lazy column. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sortedByDescending()` to filter the list, and use `take()` to get the first 10 elements. If you want to show it, you should create a new LivaData to store your filterd list:

```
val topTenScoreList : LiveData<List<ScoreDB>> =
Transformations.map(scoreList) {
            it.sortedDescending{ s->s.score }.take(10)
}
```

And use `topTenScoreList` to generate columns

Answer (score 0):

> I want to filter out this list to display the top 10 scores.

OK, so you need

1. a list
2. to the [sort the list highest to lowest](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sorted-by-descending.html) and
3. to [take](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html) the first 10 of that:

So:

```
val topTenScores = scoreList  // The live data
    .value // The actual list
    .sortedByDescending { it.score } // The list sorted by ScoreDB.score
    .take(10) // And filtering out the first 10
```